# Vim: How to read from one buffer into another

Tags: vim, buffer

In vim it easy to read a file into the current buffer with the read command:

```
:r my.file
```

But if the path to the file is really long, and the file is open in another buffer, how can I read in the contents of the buffer instead i.e.

```
:r {buffer_number}
```

Is there a way of reading from one buffer directly into another without using the yank buffer??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the command-line, you can use `#n` to address the file linked to buffer number `n`:

```
:ls      " list buffers
:r #3    " read from file associated with buffer 3
```

Note that `:r` reads from a *file*, not from a buffer and that the content of a buffer *may* be different from the content of its associated file.

You can't really avoid scripting (as in Luc Hermitte's answer) if you want to access the content of a buffer.

Comment: Indeed. My answer is much to complex. And I've learned something new. Thank :)

Answer (score 2):

You can store the content of the buffer either directly with `getline(1,'$')`, or with `readfile(bufname(buffnumber))`. But I guess the latter cannot be used in your context otherwise, you'd have used it directly with `:r`.

So, you need

- first to remember where your are. -> `getwinid()`, or with `bufnr('%')`
- then, go to a window with the right buffer, or simply to change the current buffer
- read its content
- return where you were (i.e. restore the initial buffer)
- and finally paste what you have read

It could be something like that:

```
" untested
function s:ReadBuffer(b) abort
  " + add test to be sure the buffer exists
  let b0 = bufnr('%')
  exe 'b ' . a:b
  let lines = getline(1, '$')
  exe 'b ' . b0
  $put=lines
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=buffer ReadBuffer call s:ReadBuffer(<f-args>)
```

Comment: @yolenoyer Yes indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Although I accepted the other answer I would like to thank you for your rigorous dissection of the problem